# Reviewing posts with pending edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, late-answers, new-users

When I review the First Posts or Late Answers review queues I sometimes come across posts which need to be improved (posts which are relevant and need not be flagged but just need edits like updating tags and formatting) with pending edits. As I am a user with less than 2000 rep I can't see/review what the edit is. I generally click "No Action Needed" as there is already an pending edit.

Am I doing the right thing? or Should I "Skip" the posts? or Should I favorite the post and revisit it later? or Is this some bug and posts with pending edits shouldn't be available for review?

Answer (score 1):

Just because a post has a pending edit doesn't mean that no action is needed for the post.  If the post is actually an acceptable post that doesn't require any (additional) improvement, doesn't merit flagging, doesn't need additional feedback, etc. then go ahead and mark it as no action needed.

If it merits flagging, flag it, if it needs feedback through voting, commenting, closing, etc. then provide it.

If the post would need additional editing, even if the pending edit were to be approved, then that is the only case where you wouldn't be able to properly review the post (without having 2k rep) and in those cases you should skip it.

Comment: I mean to say about post which just need edits. I do flags posts which need to be flagged even if it has pending edits. I updated the question to  make it more clear. So I should skip it then. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How can I see the pending edit when you say "post would need additional editing, even if the pending edit were to be approved" ? Is there a way to see it? the edit button is disabled . Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you please answer my question in the previous comment?

Comment: @Servy why are not you answering the OP's question in the comment?